# How to access data from promise data , when using axios instance and function? Waht to use axios instances and functions in same file and use anywhere

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-hooks, axios, use-effect

I am using axios instance, I am making a function to get data in another file and want to get data into another file, but when i do it it returns a promise as pending then after fullfilled data in promise Results.

```
** PersonAPI.js **

const axios = require("axios")

export const API = axios.create({
    baseURL:"http://localhost:5197/api/"
})


export const getPersons = async (url) =>
{
    
   const data = await API.post(url).then((res) => {
      var data = res.data  
      return data 
    })
    return data 
}
```

Now I use this function in my Form.js file and want to get the data and display after storing into the state variable using SetState.

**I am calling the getPersons function from PersonAPI.js in useEffect Hook**

```
** Form.js **

 import {API, getPersons} from "../api/PersonAPI"
 import axios from "axios"
import { useEffect, useState } from "react"

 const Form = () =>{
    const [persons,setPersons] = useState()
    const [photo,setPhoto] = useState()
    const [fname,setFname]  = useState()
    const [lname,setLname]  = useState()

    const getData = async () => {
         await API.post("http://localhost:5197/api/Person/62f79a6981c410e64270613e").then((respone) => {
            const personData = respone.data;
            // console.log(respone)
            setPersons(personData);
            setFname(personData.firstname)
            setLname(personData.lastname)
            setPhoto(personData.photo)
        });
    }

    const toBase64 = (file) =>{
        return new Promise((resolve,reject)=>{
            const fileReader = new FileReader()
            fileReader.readAsDataURL(file)
            fileReader.onload = () => {
                resolve(fileReader.result)
            }

            fileReader.onerror = (error) =>[
                reject(error)
            ]
        })
    }

    const convertPhoto = async (e) => {
        let files = e.target.files
        const base64 = await toBase64(files[0])
        setPhoto(base64)
    }

    const updateData = () => { 
        axios({
            method:"post",
            url:"http://localhost:5197/replace/62f79a6981c410e64270613e",
            data:{
                Id:"62f79a6981c410e64270613e",firstname:fname,lastname:lname,photo:photo
            },
            headers:{
                'Access-Control-Allow-Origin': '*',
                'Content-Type': 'application/json' 
            }
            
        }).then((response) => console.log(response))
    }



    useEffect(() => {
       getData()
       const result = getPersons("Person/62f79a6981c410e64270613e")
       console.log(result)
    },[])   

    return(
    <>
    <div>
        <label>Photo</label>
        <input type={'file'} defaultValue={fname} placeholder="firstname" onChange={(e) => convertPhoto(e)}/>
    </div>
    <div>
        <label>First Name</label>
        <input type={'text'} defaultValue={fname} placeholder="firstname" onChange={(e) => setFname(e.target.value)}/>
    </div>
    <div>
        <label>First Name</label>
        <input type={'text'} placeholder="lastname" defaultValue={lname} onChange={(e) => setLname(e.target.value)}/>
    </div>
    <button onClick={updateData}> Update</button>

    <div>
        <img src = {persons?.photo} alt ="Person Photo" width={'200px'} height={'150px'}/>
        <h1>{persons?.firstname}</h1>
        <h1>{persons?.lastname}</h1>
    </div>
    </>
    )

}

export default Form;
```

Comment: Your description is correct, but what is the question? You have already code that knows how to deal with a pending promise (use `await` or `then`), so just stick to that approach whenever you have a promise.

Comment: In your `form.js` you're calling `API.post` with a incorrect url (`http://localhost:5197/api/Person/62f79a6981c410e64270613e`) instead of (`Person/62f79a6981c410e64270613e`). That's maybe why you're getting no response.